# Why importing from and exporting to the same javascript file gives type not function error?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Supposed I have the following 2 Javascript files:

1) File 1:

```
const { fun2 } = require('./file2');
console.log(fun2());

exports.fun1 = () => {
   return 'abc';
};
```

2) File 2:

```
const { fun1 } = require('./file1');
console.log(fun1());

exports.fun2 = () => {
   return 'xyz';
};
```

If I run file1, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: fun1 is not a function
```

If I run file2, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: fun2 is not a function
```

What is the problem with importing from and exporting to the same file? Is there a solution? I'm using NodeJS

Comment: You're calling the function before you are defining it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because fun2 is an object that looks like this:

```
{
    fun2: function(){
        return "xyz";
    };
}
```

When you import things from file2 into file1, you aren't just importing the fun2 function. You importing an object that has the `fun2` function in it.

**Possible Solutions**
There are many different ways to fix this

1. Call `fun2.fun2()` in `file1`

Do something like this instead

```
console.log(fun2.fun2());
```

1. Require only the `fun2` function.
   When you require the module, just use the `fun2` function from that module.

```
const { fun2 } = require('./file2').fun2;
```

3. Export only the `fun2` function in `file2`
   Instead of doing `exports.fun2 = (insert function here)`, do `module.exports = (insert function here)`. This will export only the `fun2` function, so when you do `require('./file1')` it will give you a `function`.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The only solution that works is the third but I can't use it because I need to export multiple functions not one so can't add it directly as the only export. This is just a simplified demo. Other solutions give the same error

Comment: It turns out even the third solution does not work after testing

Comment: Neither of these solve the problem. I'm not even sure your explanation is correct.

Comment: What exactly does `const { fun2 } = require('./file2');` do? I don't use the brackets around the `fun2`. Try doing this along with either of the solutions in my answer: `const fun2 = require('./file2');` (without the brackets)

Answer (score 1):

This is called as circular dependency. To fix the issue, try the following.

```
// file 1
exports.fun1 = () => {
  return "abc";
};

const { fun2 } = require("./file2");
console.log(fun2());
```

and

```
// file 2
exports.fun2 = () => {
  return "xyz";
};

const { fun1 } = require("./file1");
console.log(fun1());
```

Comment: You are correct that this is a circular dependency, but that is _not_ the root cause of the problem.  The root cause, as already explained in the answer fro @programmerRaj  is that the export is an object containing the function, not just the function itself.

Comment: @EJK Making the export the function itself won't help.

Comment: @EJK This answer here doesn't change the exported object or the circular dependency, it just fixes the order in which statements are evaluated. It works, and is the correct solution. It might need a better explanation of the issue, though.

Comment: @EJK I read that circular dependencies should be avoided as much as possible as they indicate a bad code design. My real code has a model/controller design. I can avoid this circular thing altogether by having both functions in the same module which would be the controller in the actual code but the imported function belongs to another model. Is it ok in MVC to control some functions of the model from another controller or is it a bad practice?

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Sure, it's best to avoid the circular dependency altogether, but sometimes there are good reasons to have it. We can't judge your use case. If you do have one in your code, you just need to make sure that you never use/access any of the exports before both modules finished exporting all their functions. That includes function calls as well as destructuring. Make sure to [read the docs on dependency cycles](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Comment: @Bergi But is it ok to control some methods of a model from another controller (not its own)? That would decide it for me as now I have both solutions. I feel one should be more correct than the other.

Answer (score -3):

try

```
exports.fun1 = function() {
   return 'abc';
};
```

Comment: What if I have multiple functions to export? This is just a simplified version of the script

Comment: That's actually a totally irrelevant answer! My syntax is correct so syntax is not the problem